# Как исправить undefined после удаления элемента html

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, dom

Имеется два блока. Один изначально пустой, второй наполнен элементами. При клике на каждый элемент из второго блока текст элемента должен копироваться в span в первый блок, при повторном клике должен удаляться. Это я реализовал, но, если задавать стили, то при удалении элемента из первого блока вместо пустоты возникает надпись undefined. Голова уже кипит, не могу исправить.
Всё это реализовано на jquery.

```js
$(".tags__tabs--block").find(".tags__item").click(function() {
  $(this).toggleClass("tags__item--active");
  var text = "&nbsp;<span>" + $(this).text() + "</span>";

  $(".search__tags--country").html($(".search__tags--country").html().replace(text));
  if ($(this).hasClass("tags__item--active")) {
    $(".search__tags--country").append(text);
  }
});
```

```css
.tags {
  border-top: 2px solid #2B87DB;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
}

.tags__country {
  display: none;
}

.tags__country--tabs {
  padding: 47px 0px 50px 0px;
  text-align: center;
}

.tags__country--tabs input {
  display: none;
}

.tags__country--tabs input:checked+label {
  color: #2B87DB;
}

.tags__tabs--items {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  margin: 0px 0px 47px 0px;
}

.tags__tabs--item {
  margin: 0px 22px 47px;
  font-family: Nunito;
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 600;
  font-size: 24px;
  line-height: 33px;
  color: #000000;
  text-align: center;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.tags__tabs--item:hover {
  color: #2B87DB;
}

.tags__tabs--block {
  margin-top: 47px;
  transition: all 0.3s ease;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: flex-start;
}

.tags__tabs--block:target {
  display: flex;
}

.tags__items {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  align-items: start;
  margin-right: 15%;
}

.tags__item {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  padding: 3px 8.5px;
  margin: 15px auto 0px 0px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.tags__item:hover .tags__item--text {
  color: #2B87DB;
}

.tags__item--active {
  border: 2px solid #000;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border-radius: 30px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  padding: 3px 30px 3px 8.5px;
  margin: 5px auto 5px 0px;
  cursor: pointer;
  position: relative;
}

.tags__item--active:hover {
  border-color: #2B87DB;
}

.tags__item--active .tags__item--text::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  width: 15px;
  height: 15px;
  background-image: url(../img/icon_cross_1.svg);
  right: 7px;
  top: 50%;
  margin-top: -6px;
}

.tags__item--img {
  margin-right: 15px;
  max-height: 15px;
}

.tags__item--text {
  font-family: Nunito;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-size: 24px;
  line-height: 33px;
  color: #000000;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="search__item">
  <div class="search__title">Выберите страну:</div>
  <div class="search__tags search__tags--country"></div>
</div>
<div class="tags__tabs--block" id="top">
  <div class="tags__items">
    <div class="tags__item">
      <div class="tags__item--text">Австрия</div>
    </div>
    <div class="tags__item">
      <div class="tags__item--text">Дания</div>
    </div>
    <div class="tags__item">
      <div class="tags__item--text">Дания</div>
    </div>
    <div class="tags__item">
      <div class="tags__item--text">Дания</div>
    </div>
    <div class="tags__item">
      <div class="tags__item--text">Дания</div>
    </div>
    <div class="tags__item">
      <div class="tags__item--text">Нидерланды</div>
    </div>
    <div class="tags__item">
      <div class="tags__item--text">Франция</div>
    </div>
    <div class="tags__item">
      <div class="tags__item--text">Албания</div>
    </div>
    <div class="tags__item">
      <div class="tags__item--text">Ирландия</div>
    </div>
    <div class="tags__item">
      <div class="tags__item--text">Норвегия</div>
    </div>
    <div class="tags__item">
      <div class="tags__item--text">Хорватия</div>
    </div>
    <div class="tags__item">
      <div class="tags__item--text">Андорра</div>
    </div>
```

В качестве примеров
https://jsfiddle.net/s6katrgc/2/
https://mau0hezzz.h1n.ru/demo/tourism/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace

```js
$(".tags__tabs--block").find(".tags__item").click(function() {
  $(this).toggleClass("tags__item--active");
  var text = "&nbsp;<span>" + $(this).text() + "</span>";

  $(".search__tags--country").html($(".search__tags--country").html().replace(text, ""));
  //                                                                              ^^^^
  if ($(this).hasClass("tags__item--active")) {
    $(".search__tags--country").append(text);
  }
});
```

```css
.tags {
  border-top: 2px solid #2B87DB;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
}

.tags__country {
  display: none;
}

.tags__country--tabs {
  padding: 47px 0px 50px 0px;
  text-align: center;
}

.tags__country--tabs input {
  display: none;
}

.tags__country--tabs input:checked+label {
  color: #2B87DB;
}

.tags__tabs--items {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  margin: 0px 0px 47px 0px;
}

.tags__tabs--item {
  margin: 0px 22px 47px;
  font-family: Nunito;
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 600;
  font-size: 24px;
  line-height: 33px;
  color: #000000;
  text-align: center;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.tags__tabs--item:hover {
  color: #2B87DB;
}

.tags__tabs--block {
  margin-top: 47px;
  transition: all 0.3s ease;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: flex-start;
}

.tags__tabs--block:target {
  display: flex;
}

.tags__items {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  align-items: start;
  margin-right: 15%;
}

.tags__item {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  padding: 3px 8.5px;
  margin: 15px auto 0px 0px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.tags__item:hover .tags__item--text {
  color: #2B87DB;
}

.tags__item--active {
  border: 2px solid #000;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border-radius: 30px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  padding: 3px 30px 3px 8.5px;
  margin: 5px auto 5px 0px;
  cursor: pointer;
  position: relative;
}

.tags__item--active:hover {
  border-color: #2B87DB;
}

.tags__item--active .tags__item--text::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  width: 15px;
  height: 15px;
  background-image: url(../img/icon_cross_1.svg);
  right: 7px;
  top: 50%;
  margin-top: -6px;
}

.tags__item--img {
  margin-right: 15px;
  max-height: 15px;
}

.tags__item--text {
  font-family: Nunito;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-size: 24px;
  line-height: 33px;
  color: #000000;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="search__item">
  <div class="search__title">Выберите страну:</div>
  <div class="search__tags search__tags--country"></div>
</div>
<div class="tags__tabs--block" id="top">
  <div class="tags__items">
    <div class="tags__item">
      <div class="tags__item--text">Австрия</div>
    </div>
    <div class="tags__item">
      <div class="tags__item--text">Дания</div>
    </div>
    <div class="tags__item">
      <div class="tags__item--text">Дания</div>
    </div>
    <div class="tags__item">
      <div class="tags__item--text">Дания</div>
    </div>
    <div class="tags__item">
      <div class="tags__item--text">Дания</div>
    </div>
    <div class="tags__item">
      <div class="tags__item--text">Нидерланды</div>
    </div>
    <div class="tags__item">
      <div class="tags__item--text">Франция</div>
    </div>
    <div class="tags__item">
      <div class="tags__item--text">Албания</div>
    </div>
    <div class="tags__item">
      <div class="tags__item--text">Ирландия</div>
    </div>
    <div class="tags__item">
      <div class="tags__item--text">Норвегия</div>
    </div>
    <div class="tags__item">
      <div class="tags__item--text">Хорватия</div>
    </div>
    <div class="tags__item">
      <div class="tags__item--text">Андорра</div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Спасибо, помогло. А есть возможность по клику удалить элемент из первого блока (в который копировали) с отменой класса tags__item--active у изначального блока?