# Удаление скопированного элемента jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Имеется код ниже. При клике на название страны её название отображается в span в верхнем блоке и этому элементу присваивается класс, при повторном клике на это же название span сверху исчезает. Подскажите как при клике на span убирать класс у изначального элемента (у которого взят текст) и удалять span, на который кликнули?

```js
$(".tags__tabs--block").find(".tags__item").click(function() {
  $(this).toggleClass("tags__item--active");
  var text = "&nbsp;<span>" + $(this).text() + "</span>";

  $(".search__tags--country").html($(".search__tags--country").html().replace(text));
  if ($(this).hasClass("tags__item--active")) {
    $(".search__tags--country").append(text);
  }
});
```

```css
.tags {
  border-top: 2px solid #2B87DB;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
}

.tags__country {
  display: none;
}

.tags__country--tabs {
  padding: 47px 0px 50px 0px;
  text-align: center;
}

.tags__country--tabs input {
  display: none;
}

.tags__country--tabs input:checked+label {
  color: #2B87DB;
}

.tags__tabs--items {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  margin: 0px 0px 47px 0px;
}

.tags__tabs--item {
  margin: 0px 22px 47px;
  font-family: Nunito;
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 600;
  font-size: 24px;
  line-height: 33px;
  color: #000000;
  text-align: center;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.tags__tabs--item:hover {
  color: #2B87DB;
}

.tags__tabs--block {
  margin-top: 47px;
  transition: all 0.3s ease;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: flex-start;
}

.tags__tabs--block:target {
  display: flex;
}

.tags__items {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  align-items: start;
  margin-right: 15%;
}

.tags__item {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  padding: 3px 8.5px;
  margin: 15px auto 0px 0px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.tags__item:hover .tags__item--text {
  color: #2B87DB;
}

.tags__item--active {
  border: 2px solid #000;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border-radius: 30px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  padding: 3px 30px 3px 8.5px;
  margin: 5px auto 5px 0px;
  cursor: pointer;
  position: relative;
}

.tags__item--active:hover {
  border-color: #2B87DB;
}

.tags__item--active .tags__item--text::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  width: 15px;
  height: 15px;
  background-image: url(../img/icon_cross_1.svg);
  right: 7px;
  top: 50%;
  margin-top: -6px;
}

.tags__item--img {
  margin-right: 15px;
  max-height: 15px;
}

.tags__item--text {
  font-family: Nunito;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-size: 24px;
  line-height: 33px;
  color: #000000;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="search__item">
  <div class="search__title">Выберите страну:</div>
  <div class="search__tags search__tags--country"></div>
</div>
<div class="tags__tabs--block" id="top">
  <div class="tags__items">
    <div class="tags__item">
      <div class="tags__item--text">Австрия</div>
    </div>
    <div class="tags__item">
      <div class="tags__item--text">Дания</div>
    </div>
    <div class="tags__item">
      <div class="tags__item--text">Дания</div>
    </div>
    <div class="tags__item">
      <div class="tags__item--text">Дания</div>
    </div>
    <div class="tags__item">
      <div class="tags__item--text">Дания</div>
    </div>
    <div class="tags__item">
      <div class="tags__item--text">Нидерланды</div>
    </div>
    <div class="tags__item">
      <div class="tags__item--text">Франция</div>
    </div>
    <div class="tags__item">
      <div class="tags__item--text">Албания</div>
    </div>
    <div class="tags__item">
      <div class="tags__item--text">Ирландия</div>
    </div>
    <div class="tags__item">
      <div class="tags__item--text">Норвегия</div>
    </div>
    <div class="tags__item">
      <div class="tags__item--text">Хорватия</div>
    </div>
    <div class="tags__item">
      <div class="tags__item--text">Андорра</div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Это что такое? - `...replace(text)` https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1231084

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```js
let selection = [];

function applySelection(){
  $(".search__tags--country").html(
    selection.map((x) => `<span>${x.name}</span>`).join('&nbsp;')
  );
}

$(".tags__tabs--block .tags__item").click(function() {
  $(this).toggleClass("tags__item--active");

  const isActive = $(this).hasClass("tags__item--active");
  const country = $(this).text();
  const index = $(this).index();

  if (isActive) {
    selection.push({
      name: country,
      el: this,
      index
    });
  } else {
    selection = selection.filter((x) => !(x.name === country && x.index === index));
  }
  
  applySelection();
});

$(".search__tags--country").on('click', 'span', function() {
  const index = $(this).index();
  const [ item ] = selection.splice(index, 1);

  applySelection();
  
  $(item.el).toggleClass("tags__item--active");
});
```

```css
.tags {
  border-top: 2px solid #2B87DB;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
}

.tags__country {
  display: none;
}

.tags__country--tabs {
  padding: 47px 0px 50px 0px;
  text-align: center;
}

.tags__country--tabs input {
  display: none;
}

.tags__country--tabs input:checked+label {
  color: #2B87DB;
}

.tags__tabs--items {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  margin: 0px 0px 47px 0px;
}

.tags__tabs--item {
  margin: 0px 22px 47px;
  font-family: Nunito;
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 600;
  font-size: 24px;
  line-height: 33px;
  color: #000000;
  text-align: center;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.tags__tabs--item:hover {
  color: #2B87DB;
}

.tags__tabs--block {
  margin-top: 47px;
  transition: all 0.3s ease;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: flex-start;
}

.tags__tabs--block:target {
  display: flex;
}

.tags__items {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  align-items: start;
  margin-right: 15%;
}

.tags__item {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  padding: 3px 8.5px;
  margin: 15px auto 0px 0px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.tags__item:hover .tags__item--text {
  color: #2B87DB;
}

.tags__item--active {
  border: 2px solid #000;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border-radius: 30px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  padding: 3px 30px 3px 8.5px;
  margin: 5px auto 5px 0px;
  cursor: pointer;
  position: relative;
}

.tags__item--active:hover {
  border-color: #2B87DB;
}

.tags__item--active .tags__item--text::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  width: 15px;
  height: 15px;
  background-image: url(../img/icon_cross_1.svg);
  right: 7px;
  top: 50%;
  margin-top: -6px;
}

.tags__item--img {
  margin-right: 15px;
  max-height: 15px;
}

.tags__item--text {
  font-family: Nunito;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-size: 24px;
  line-height: 33px;
  color: #000000;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="search__item">
  <div class="search__title">Выберите страну:</div>
  <div class="search__tags search__tags--country"></div>
</div>
<div class="tags__tabs--block" id="top">
  <div class="tags__items">
    <div class="tags__item">
      <div class="tags__item--text">Австрия</div>
    </div>
    <div class="tags__item">
      <div class="tags__item--text">Дания</div>
    </div>
    <div class="tags__item">
      <div class="tags__item--text">Дания</div>
    </div>
    <div class="tags__item">
      <div class="tags__item--text">Дания</div>
    </div>
    <div class="tags__item">
      <div class="tags__item--text">Дания</div>
    </div>
    <div class="tags__item">
      <div class="tags__item--text">Нидерланды</div>
    </div>
    <div class="tags__item">
      <div class="tags__item--text">Франция</div>
    </div>
    <div class="tags__item">
      <div class="tags__item--text">Албания</div>
    </div>
    <div class="tags__item">
      <div class="tags__item--text">Ирландия</div>
    </div>
    <div class="tags__item">
      <div class="tags__item--text">Норвегия</div>
    </div>
    <div class="tags__item">
      <div class="tags__item--text">Хорватия</div>
    </div>
    <div class="tags__item">
      <div class="tags__item--text">Андорра</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Он хочет кликать на название страны маленькими буквами вверху.

Comment: @Igor а. сейчас дорисую

Comment: https://qna.habr.com/q/919621 чё то он мутит ...